# Is Ghost's "Square Hammer" a cover?

Tags: cover

I recently discovered the band "Ghost" and one of their songs named "Square Hammer" sounds so awefully familiar.

[Youtube: Ghost - Square Hammer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqoyKzgkqR4)

Is this song a cover or contains some very similar elements from another famous song? Especially the intro part on the organ. Haven't found anything that says it's a cover, but it sounds so familiar...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No

This song is not a cover from another artist.

The song was released in a EP called [*Popestar*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Ghost-Popestar/release/9058892) and is credited [**A Ghoul Writer**](https://www.discogs.com/fr/artist/3141688-A-Ghoul-Writer) which is an alias for the band credits.

The intro vaguely reminds me Dio's *Rainbow in the Dark* but I can't read your mind to know what it reminds you ("read-my-mind" questions are off-topic).

Comment: Not meant to be off topic, of course you can't know how what it reminds me of =) But it's enough for me if your say it's definitely not a cover. I just thought that the melody might be a hommage to something.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to this one...  very much NOT the same, but this is what comes to mind. "National Aerobic Championship Theme"

Then go watch the Kee and Peele skit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4k-Dd71CqnM

Answer (score 1):

I'd hazard a guess it reminds you of:

The Police - [Message in a Bottle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbXWrmQW-OE)

The rhythm, the sound of the instrument and the specific melody of the riff are all very similar.

Comment: Wow, you are right